# CSV file export in MATLAB adding new lines

Tags: matlab, csv

I'm trying to take in a complex csv file in MATLAB and edit/rearrange it. I used tableread to pull out the numerical data that I then manipulated. Afterwards I aimed to take the first 52 rows of text metadata, add three more rows then combine with the numerical data and output as a csv file.

However, I can't seem to find a way to work with the text metadata rows that doesn't ultimately add new lines between them when output.
e.g. this is how my csv outputs:

> #HEADER
> ,,,,,,
> Instrument, Data Processed Analysis
> ,,,,,
> Version,1.3.1,1.25
> ,,,,
> Created,Monday, August 16, 2021 3:13:38 PM
> ,,,
> Filename,D5-116.NGXDP
> ,,,,,

When it should look like:

> #HEADER
> NGX, Data Processed Analysis
> Version,1.3.1,1.25
> Created,Monday, August 16, 2021 3:13:38 PM
> Filename,D5-116.NGXDP

Here is my code:

`

```
close  
clear  

fileName = 'D5-116.NGXDP';  
fileOut = fileName(1:end-6);  
fileOut = append(fileOut, '.csv');  
eEnergy = 1.602176634e-19; %electron energy in coulombs  
resisTor = 1e11; %Resistor value for EM  
  
%% Reading and Edit Mass Data - this is too hardcoded right now  
T = readtable(fileName, 'FileType', 'text');  
T = T{:,:}; %convert from table to matrix  
    
dataOrg(:,1:3) = T(1087:1236, 1:3); %cycle:time:Ar  
dataOrg(:,4) = T(935:1084, 3); %39  
dataOrg(:,5) = T(783:932, 3); %38  
dataOrg(:,6) = T(631:780, 3); %37  
dataOrg(:,7) = T(479:628, 3); %36  
  
dataOrg(:,7) = dataOrg(:,7) * eEnergy * resisTor; %36Ar - convert CPS to V  
dataOrg(:,3:7) = dataOrg(:,3:7) * 1000; %Convert all to mV  
  
%% Reading the metadata from the file  
  
T2 = fopen(fileName);  
metaData = fread(T2, '*char')'; %read content  
fclose(T2);  
results = strsplit(metaData, '\n'); %split the char data by entry spaces  
  
metaNeat = results(:,1:52)'; %Takes the metadata prior to #collectors  
  
metaNeat(end+1, 1) = {'Blocks, 1'}; %added data 
metaNeat(end+1, 1) = {'Cycles, 150'}; %added data 
metaNeat(end+1, 1) = {'Cycle, Time, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36'};  
  
for n = 1:length(metaNeat) %scan each row, if there is a comma split them  
   if contains(metaNeat(n,1), ',') == 1  
       tempMeta = split(metaNeat(n,1), ',')';  
       metaNeat(n,1:size(tempMeta, 2)) = tempMeta;   
       clear tempMeta  
   end  
end  
  
outPut = metaNeat; %metadata section  
outPut(end+1:(end+150), 1:7) = num2cell(dataOrg); %mass value section  
writecell(outPut,fileOut,'Delimiter',',', 'FileType', 'text')
```

I'm sure there is a way to do this in three lines of course. My guess is that the strsplit function I'm using to separate the char cell into multiple rows is preserving the \n value. The added lines (e.g. Blocks, 1) do not show gaps in the csv file. Any tips or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: I assume the header output is up front.  What does `outPut(1:5,:)` contain?

Comment: Also you can read in `T2` with `metaData = textscan(T2, '%s','delimiter','\n');` and you will have the rows ready to go with no need to do more.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. outPut(1:5,:) contains: 5×7 cell array
 Columns 1 through 5
    {'#HEADER←'}    {0×0 double         }    {0×0 double  }    {0×0 double         }    {0×0 double}
    {'NGX'      }    {' Data Processed…'}    {0×0 double  }    {0×0 double         }    {0×0 double}
    {'Version'  }    {'1.3.1'            }    {'1.25←'    }    {0×0 double         }    {0×0 double}
    {'Created'  }    {'Monday'           }    {' August 16'}    {' 2021 3:13:38 P…'}    {0×0 double}
    {'Filename' }    {'D5-116.NGXDP←'   }    {0×0 double  }    {0×0 double         }    {0×0 double}

Comment: there's the problem.  You need to step through your code in debugger and figure out where those empty rows are coming from.  Each of those `{0x0 double}` are the empty comas entries you're seeing.  Without the actual data/files you're working with I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your time. The empty spaces come when I convert the char into a cell array, since some rows have 7 columns everything else is filled with empty space. Even if I convert all the empty space using isempty to something else (like spaces) I still get extra rows on the output csv file. I'll keep playing with it and see if I can work it out. I likely need to keep it as a single cell like textscan produces.

Comment: The issue was the strsplit I think. The following code works: ```T2 = fopen(fileName);  
metaData2=textscan(T2, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');  
metaNeat = metaData2{1,1}(1:52,1);  
metaNeat(1:end, 2:7) = repmat({''}, size(metaNeat, 1), 6);  
for n = 1:length(metaNeat)  
   if contains(metaNeat(n,1), ',') == 1  
       tempMeta = split(metaNeat(n,1), ',')';  
       metaNeat(n,1:size(tempMeta, 2)) = tempMeta;   
       clear tempMeta  
   end  
end  
outPut = [metaNeat;num2cell(dataOrg)];  
writecell(outPut,fileOut,'Delimiter',',', 'FileType', 'text')  ```